# Как одним сервлетом передать запрос другому сервлету

Tags: java, servlet

Как одним сервлетом передать запрос другому сервлету. Если сервлеты лежат в одном пакете какой будет  url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, можете вызвать из первого сервлета `request.getRequestDispatcher("<урл второго сервлета>").forward(request, response);`

Comment: Если сервлеты лежат в одном пакете, как будет выглядеть путь?

Comment: Там важно не в каком пакете лежат сервлеты, а маппинг на них

Comment: Прошу пояснить, что значит маппинг

Comment: Маппинг - это указание, по какому адресу будет доступен сервлет. Указывается либо в web.xml либо при помощи аннотаций. Посмотрите пример: http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Comment: Есть ещё такая функция: `request.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(servletName).forward(...)` Используется имя сервлета. Имя назначается в web.xml. И ещё `request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(...)` немного отличается от предложенного уже `request.getRequestDispatcher(...)`